# How do i use a cell in a formula to take info from a sheet that has the same name as the cell context?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

To explain my terrible title...

Lets say i have an excel (well its a google sheets file, but they are similar, except when they arent XD). This file has 200 tabs with lets say client names as their titles. and i also have a summary sheet with a table with much general info and in the table i have a column with the exact same names to those sheets (client names).

as i am trying to automate and add some functionality to that summary sheet (AND HAVE EXTRA OTHER SHEETS take info from the summary sheet) i want to find a way to use the names of clients from that column in 'summary' to have formulas go pick up specific cells from said sheets.

So:
1* sheet 'summary'
200*sheets "clients-names"

in 'summary' there is a **table**, with column with clients names (exact same text as the names of the sheets).

lets say i want a formula that in sheet 'summary', in cell A2 would pick the name of a sheet from the table, lets say from cell B2, and then it would bring up the information from the relevant sheet (named in cell B2) from lets say cell C2.

i can create manually connections for ALL the sheets and cells needed, but it would take a lot of time and the problem is that new sheets will be added (and the info to table) and some are gonna be deleted... and biggest problem is the file is gonna be used by sb else, so i want to set it uip to work and not have them "work on it" as they dont have much experience with spreadsheets (well way less than me)

Comment: Check [INDIRECT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) for an Excel solution (don't know if there is the same in Google Sheets)

Comment: For what it's worth, as an expert who's been developing spreadsheet solutions of all sizes since spreadsheets were first introduced to the world, whenever I hear someone say that they have "200+ individual sheets of data with one summary sheet," I can't help but think that this is backward. Instead, the norm would be to create ONE database/master, and then have other sheets present various "reports" from that master sheet (which can often be done in just ONE sheet wherein any "client name" can be searched/reported, rather than needing 200+ sheets).

Comment: @ErikTyler well first it is in google files so about 35 people can work on it together. its 200 tabs as client names because 1- thats how i was asked to make it after i made something closer to your proposal and it wasnt liked by management,
2- the summary tab is be updated by a secretary and add the new tab (with the clients name) and then some of the 35 people working  in the company are supposed to be inputting all the tasks that they have completed for said clients.

we could have used a project management software, but "oh it costs 10$ a month!!! we can do that with an excel".

Comment: Ah. If management is that tight with their money, there isn't much that can be done anyway. I'm surprised they have money to pay you to do anything on it, as that would most surely be far and away more than $10/month. But it looks like you solved the immediate issue. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to input this in cell A1 in my 'summary' sheet:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&B2&"'!C2")
```